# Weird spacing in my UI layout

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pyqt4

whenever I run this script of mine, the layout of my elements are somewhat in the correct area but the spacing in the right column (where the labels/button/line edit resides) makes it very unsightly with weird spacing in between them.

Any ideas how I can kill it off? Or perhaps is the using of gridLayout not a wise choice?

```
 class createUI(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent =None):
        QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):   
        self.objLbl = QLabel('Name of Item')
        self.objTxt = QLineEdit()
        self.objTxt.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.renameLbl = QLabel('Rename')
        self.renameTxt = QLineEdit()
        self.renameTxt.setMaximumWidth(100)

        self.itemLbl = QLabel('Item Lists')
        self.itemList = QListWidget()

        self.okButton = QPushButton('OK')
        self.okButton.setMaximumWidth(100)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.itemLbl,1,0)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.itemList,2,0,6,1)


        gridLayout.addWidget(self.objLbl,2,1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.objTxt,3,1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.renameLbl,4,1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.renameTxt,5,1)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.okButton,7,1)

        self.setLayout(gridLayout)  
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing")
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert a spacer with vertical strech above the OK button:

```
    gridLayout.addWidget(self.renameTxt,5,1)

    gridLayout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
        0, 0, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding), 6, 1)

    gridLayout.addWidget(self.okButton,7,1)
```